# How to fix 'Notice Undefined index:'

Tags: php, html

I received the following error message when I go on searchproduct page. How may i fixed it?

Notice: Undefined index: dosageForm in C:\xampp\htdocs\prism\searchproduct.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: dosageForm in C:\xampp\htdocs\prism\searchproduct.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: strengths in C:\xampp\htdocs\prism\searchproduct.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: strengths in C:\xampp\htdocs\prism\searchproduct.php on line 38

```
if($_POST['dataType']!= "") {
  $dataType = $_POST['dataType']; 
}else{
  $dataType = $_GET['dataType']; 
}

if($_POST['drugCategory']!= ""){
    $drugCategory = $_POST['drugCategory']; 
}else{
    $drugCategory = $_GET['drugCategory']; 
}

if($_POST['productName']!= ""){
    $productName = $_POST['productName']; 
}else{
    $productName = $_GET['productName']; 
}

if($_POST['brandName']!= ""){
    $brandName = $_POST['brandName']; 
}else{
    $brandName = $_GET['brandName']; 
}

if($_POST['dosageForm']!= ""){
    $dosageForm = $_POST['dosageForm']; 
}else{
    $dosageForm = $_GET['dosageForm']; 
}

if($_POST['strengths']!= ""){
    $strengths = $_POST['strengths']; 
}else{
    $strengths = $_GET['strengths']; 
}
```

i am getting same type of error ,

please help me to resolve

Comment: The Notice comes up because you're trying to access items in an array that don't exist. It's not a problem, but PHP will spawn a Notice on it, because it's not the intended way to do it. Check if something is set through isset or !empty. And on another note, you _could_ use $_REQUEST [http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php], which has a combined array of _POST, _GET, and _COOKIE. That way all your if else statements are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `isset()`

```
if(isset($_POST['drugCategory']))
```

or in your case : `empty()`

```
 if(!empty($_POST['drugCategory']))
```

**Update:**

PHP7.1 allow this one too but it will may be forbidden by CodeStyle's rules

```
if($_POST['drugCategory'] ?? false)
```